# How to specify equivalant of null as default parameter of struct type

Tags: c#, struct

How can I define a function so that a struct parameter can be optionally passed, yet be able to know inside the function whether it was passed or not? What I am trying to accomplish would be similar to:

```
function SomeFunction(string str = null)
{
    if (str == null) { ... }
}
```

Calling the above function with no parameter would trigger the `if (str == null)...` condition:

```
SomeFunction();
```

The above approach doesn't work with a parameter of type struct. Given the following struct:

```
public struct MyStruct
{
    public int SomeInt;
    public double SomeDouble;
}
```

This generates an error that there are no standard conversions:

```
public function SomeFunction(MyStruct mystruct = null) { }
```

But when I define the function as:

```
public function SomeFunction(MyStruct mystruct = default(MyStruct)) { }
```

And call the function with:

```
SomeFunction();
```

On entry to the function `mystruct` contains 0 for `SomeInt` and 0.00 for `SomeDouble`. These could be legit values which leaves me without a way to know if the parameter was actually passed to the function or left empty.

How can I define this parameter so that if it is not specified in the call I can detect that within the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use nullable types (optionally with overloaded methods as shown below with `DoSomething`) to check whether a value was passed or not.

```
public function SomeFunction(MyStruct? mystruct)
{
   if(mystruct.HasValue)
       DoSomething(mystruct.Value);
   else
       DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: This might be the best way to go as pointed out by TGH also. I can live with it, but I am still forced to specify a `null` in the call to the function? In other words, I can't just leave it empty in the call since nullable doesn't provide a default value for the called function?

Comment: If you want to pass in an empty parameter rather than `null`, use overloaded methods.

ie. `public function SomeFunction(){ SomeFunction(null); }`

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Both you and TGH provided the same answer. I wish I could mark them both as correct... On one hand TGH answered first. On the other he has a lot more points than you. :S I dislike having to mark either as an answer because the choice is tough. You provided more input/followup. So thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function SomeFunction(MyStruct? mystruct) { }
```

You can use nullable types

Comment: Very obvious now that you pointed it out! I didn't think of that. Thank you TGH.